# jQuery formBuilder how to display form data in XML?

Tags: jquery, xml, formbuilder

I am using the jQuery formBuilder plugin. I have read the documentation but it seems the getData action can only alert form data in XML. My question is, how do I display it in a div?

https://codepen.io/kevinchappell/pen/zwrddy

```
var fbTemplate = document.getElementById('form-wrap');
var formBuilder = jQuery(fbTemplate).formBuilder(options);

document.getElementById('getXML').addEventListener('click', function() {
// alert(formBuilder.actions.getData('xml'));
previewData = formBuilder.formData;
let html = '<!doctype html><title>Form Preview</title><body class="container"><h1>Preview</h1><hr>'+previewData+'</body></html>';
var formPreviewWindow = window.open('', 'formPreview', 'height=480,width=640,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes');
formPreviewWindow.document.write(html);
```

});

Comment: do you want to display into which div?

Comment: I'm sorry, not div. I want to display it in formPreviewWindow.

Comment: where is formPreviewWindow in your code?

Comment: It's on the 8th line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add data using below code:

demo: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/rKwOzb

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var fbEditor = document.getElementById('build-wrap');
    var formBuilder = $(fbEditor).formBuilder();
    document.getElementById('getXML').addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert(formBuilder.actions.getData('xml'));
        htmldata = formBuilder.actions.getData('xml');
        previewData = formBuilder.formData;
        let html = '<!doctype html><title>Form Preview</title><body class="container"><h1>Preview</h1><hr><pre>' + htmldata + '</pre></body></html>';
        console.log(htmldata)
        var formPreviewWindow = window.open('', 'formPreview', 'height=480,width=640,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes');
        formPreviewWindow.document.write(html);
    });
    document.getElementById('getJSON').addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(formBuilder.actions.getData('json'));
    });
    document.getElementById('getJS').addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('check console');
        console.log(formBuilder.actions.getData());


    });

});
```

Comment: console.log(htmldata) does work, but I can't figure out how to display it in a new window.

Comment: its dispalying in new window!!

Comment: check now. Updated Fiddle!!

Comment: okay thanks @BhumiShah... i need the xml format here...